# IosNotificationSettings no existe a partir de la 9.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, ios, firebase-messaging

Tengo una aplicación de flutter muy desactualizada. Actualicé las dependencias y actualicé **firebase_messaging** a la última versión. En la versión 9.0.0 IosNotificationSettings desapareció, quisiera saber si existe alguna alternativa.

Este es el método donde lo uso:

```
void iOS_Permission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
    {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, estamos en la version de SO de español, te recomiendo [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/542297/edit) la pregunta y hacerla en español, de lo contrario acabara cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según he encontrado en [el cambio de versiones del Github de flutter](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/4012) de la versión `8.0.0`

> requestNotificationPermissions() has been deprecated in favor of requestPermission()

Es decir, deprecaron `requestNotificationPermissions()`, y en su lugar has de usar `requestPermission()`, supongo que al pasar a la versión `9.0.0` y al estar deprecada en la `8.0.0`, lo eliminaron completamente.

También hablan de tu problema en específico:

> **DEPRECATED: `IosNotificationSettings`**
>
> Usage of the IosNotificationSettings class is now deprecated (currently used with the now deprecated requestNotificationPermissions() method).
>
> Instead of this class, use named arguments when calling requestPermission() and read the permissions back via NotificationSettings.

Básicamente, que utilices lo arriba mencionado (que utilices `requestPermission()`), esto será debido a lo mencionado anteriormente, que han deprecado todo lo que tenía que ver con `requestNotificationPermissions()`

Revisa bien los cambios de versiones desde tu anterior versión hasta la `9.0.0` uno a uno, te podrían pasar más cosas por el estilo.